# fish shell - Showing the current command in the window title of screen

Tags: gnu-screen, fish

I want the current command to be shown in the title of screen (or tmux).

I tried following settings but it doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

**.screenrc**

```
shelltitle "$ |fish"
shell /usr/local/bin/fish
```

**.config/fish/config.fish**

```
set -x PS1 '\033k\033\\[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
Finally, this made it work!

**.screenrc**

```
shelltitle "$ |fish"
shell /usr/local/bin/fish
```

**.config/fish/config.fish**

```
function fish_prompt
    echo -ne '\033k'
    echo -ne $argv
    echo -ne '\033\\'
    echo -ne '$ '
end
```

Answer (score 8):

For fish version 2.1.0 you only have to edit **~/.config/fish/functions/fish_title.fish**

```
function fish_title
    hostname
end
```

For version 1.23.1 this doesn't seem to work. If the directories do not exist, first create them:

**mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/functions/**

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me in `.config/fish/functions/fish_title.fish` :

```
function fish_title
    # this one sets the X terminal window title
    # argv[1] has the full command line
    echo (hostname): (pwd): $argv[1]

    switch "$TERM"
    case 'screen*'

      # prepend hostname to screen(1) title only if on ssh
      if set -q SSH_CLIENT
        set maybehost (hostname):
      else
        set maybehost ""
      end

      # inside the function fish_title(), we need to
      # force stdout to reach the terminal
      #
      # (status current-command) gives only the command name
      echo -ne "\\ek"$maybehost(status current-command)"\\e\\" > /dev/tty
    end
end
```

Comment: Indeed, the last `>/dev/tty` is very important for **GNU screen**. I found the other answers failed at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `fish_title`. See [documentation here](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#title).

You could do something like this:

```
function fish_title
    echo $_ ' '
    pwd
end
funcsave fish_title
```

(Note you just run this at a prompt - don't put it in a config file).

Comment: I added the same answer and deleted it. The user is looking to update the **screen** title, not the terminal title.