# How to set tab title of gnome-terminal in fish?

Tags: fish, gnome-terminal

It's gnome-terminal 3.18.3 in ubuntu 16.04. And fish 2.2.0.
Thanks.

PS. I have a script to do it in bash, but it does not work in fish..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by implementing the `fish_title` function. See [fish shell - Showing the current command in the window title of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885174/fish-shell-showing-the-current-command-in-the-window-title-of-screen)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can use fish_title to set static title. But I want to set different title for each tab, do you have an example to do that?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out now... Thanks!